# How Do I Get a CiviCRM Report to be an attachment in a schedule job to email to a colleague?

Tags: wordpress, reports, pdf, scheduled-job

I have created some reports for our membership director and have set up scheduled jobs to email those reports on the first day of each month.

I tested them out but got lines of code and then the report was embedded in the body of the email. I'd prefer to have the reports as attachments in PDF or csv format.

How do we set this up?

Our site is on WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

One of the scheduled job parameters is "format". See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_mail_report

Comment: I have format set to PDF. Should this be lower case?

Comment: Yes, or you should be able to leave it out altogether to get pdf, but yes small letters.